# How to use different assets (audio, sprites and text) in Unity for different languages in a game?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing a Unity 2D game where a user can select a language on the home screen and then the subsequent game should be played in the selected language itself. The language specific changes include audio files, sprites and text on Canvas UI elements. How can I approach this problem?

Comment: [This question does not show research effort](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/). there are **tons** of localization scripts on the web, and several high quality solutions on the Asset Store.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit. There are different approaches for that.

I would probably do it with nested dictionaries and enums but there might be more elegant solutions.

1. Let's say you have a certain label for each text, sprite, sound, etc. in some enums like

   ```c#
   enum TextLabel{
       MainPanelTitle,
       FireButton,
       InfoText,
       ...
   }

   enum SpriteLabel{
       LanguageFlag,
       Background,
       ...
   }

   enum SoundLabel{
       WelcomeMessage,
       NationalHymn,
       ...
   }
   ```
2. And for the language you would also have an enum like

   ```c#
   enum Language{
       English,
       French,
       German,
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Than you would setup an individual dictionary for each language like

   ```c#
   // Maps text labels to English texts
   Dictionary<TextLabel,string> englishTexts;

   // Maps text labels to french texts
   Dictionary<TextLabel,string> frenchTexts;

   // Maps text labels to German texts
   Dictionary<TextLabel,string> germanTexts;

   ...
   ```

   The same for Sprites (`Dictionary<SpriteLabel,Sprite>`) and Sounds (`Dictionary<SoundLabel, AudioClip>`)
4. You make like a main dictionary for each type for selecting the correct text/image/sound dictionary depending on the language:

   ```c#
   Dictionary<Language, Dictionary<TextLabel,string>> texts;
   ```

   Again the same with sprites and sounds.
5. Than at some point you have to fill the dictionaries. The `texts` (`sounds`, `sprites`) dictionary is the simplets one since it doesn't depend on external data:

   ```c#
   texts = new Dictionary<Language, Dictionary<TextLabel,string>>(){
       {Language.English, englishTexts},
       {Language.French, frenchTexts},
       {Language.German, germanTexts},
       ...
   };
   ```
6. Well, now you "only" have to fill the information somehow into e.g. the text dictionaries. You can do this hardcoded in a script, drag/type in via the inspector or especially for texts e.g. use a .cvs table and parse that in during runtime. There are a lot of options for that step and it probably would fit for another question. In the end all will resume in some lines like

   ```c#
   englishTexts[MainPanelTitle] = ...;
   englishTexts[FireButton] = ...;
   ...

   frenchTexts[MainPanelTitle] = ...;
   ...
   ```
7. Once e.g. the text dictionaries are filled with the information you can access a certain text (e.g. InfoText in French ) like

   ```c#
   string infotext = texts[Language.French][TextLabel.InfoText];
   ```

As I said probably not the most elegant solution but that's how I would do it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I do it before by this track

```
Var string Language;

    Var UItext Title;
```

Then create buttons to choose language

in English button :

```
Language = “English”;
```

Then check what user choose

```
If (Language == “English”) {
Title = “Title Game” ;
}else if (Language == “Arabic”) {
Title = “عنوان اللعبة" ;
}
```